# Property of class exists but undefined

Tags: javascript, angular6

I have a function to collect data when I click on the row, I keep the data in the object. When I log the object, it returns object type. But when I try to log its property, it is undefined.

```
branchToDivision: BranchDto;
    onSelect(record: BranchDto) {

        this.branchToDivision = record;
        console.log(this.branchToDivision);
        console.log(this.branchToDivision.brancH_CODE);

    }
```

[console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78ELs.png)

> GetBranchForView {branch: BranchDto}
>
> undefined

I don't know what problem is.

[Here is Object definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fGwX.png)

[Console display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjj3P.png)

Comment: if you expand the "GetBranchForView" in the console... you would see the properties... do you see "brancH_CODE" there?

Comment: Can I see the definition of the object and if so, the code where you fill the object.

Comment: @AIqbalRaj In the console, brancH_CODE is displayed with value.

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the console... maybe there is something which is not letting this to you...

Comment: Can you try with `this.branchToDivision = record.branch;`?

Comment: In the definition, `brancH_CODE` is allowed to be undefined so why are you expecting a value?

Comment: @AIqbalRaj I just edited my post, you can see 3rd picture

Comment: Hi @Kokodoko I use framework Aspnetzero, Abp Template. There is a tool will map API, entity, class on server to client. So fl your question, It is a template.

Comment: Yes, and the template allows the value to be undefined. So you could check if the value exists on the `record` at all, before you assign it to `branchToDivision`

Comment: Hi @Kokodoko, your idea is nice, I can get all of the property of `record` but when I assign it to object, It is still undefined

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

`console.log(this.branchToDivision.branch.brancH_CODE);`

Comment: I get a message for your way "Property branch does not exists on type BranchDto". I changed my function a little bit.

onSelect(record: any) {
  this.branchToDivision = record;
  console.log(record.branch.brancH_CODE);
 }

I can get the value. But I want to pass data by object

Comment: when you do this.branchToDivision = record; ... the object is copied to this.branchToDivision... you can try this.branchToDivision = JSON.parse(record); and then console.log(this.branchToDivision.branch.brancH_CODE); ...

Comment: Hi @AIqbalRaj, I still can not make it work, Could I contact you for the solution?

Comment: sure, how do you want to connect?

Comment: Skype or Facebook VideoCall is better for you?

Comment: I do not have enough reputation. How about gmail? I will send you source code and the problem I meet.

Comment: sure, fire away at ai.websitefeedback@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer. Each line on the datatable is represented by a class called GetBranchForView. So when I try to catch the event I have to pass a param with type GetBranchForView. This works for me.

```
onSelect(record: GetBranchForView) {
        this.item = record;
        this.branchToDivision = record.branch;
    }
```